# Condition is not working in php

Tags: php

Here is my entire code:

```
<?php
require_once 'lib/shopify.php';
//require_once 'csv.php';
function csvToJson($csv)
{
    $rows = explode("\n", trim($csv));
    $csvarr = array_map(function($row)
    {
        $keys = array(
            'var0',
            'var1',
            'var2',
            'var3',
            'var4',
            'var5',
            'var6',
            'var7',
            'var8',
            'var9'
        );
        return array_combine($keys, str_getcsv($row));
    }, $rows);
    $json   = json_encode($csvarr);

    return $json;
}

$t     = "bac2486aa2b31aa5aed1fdd62e77a4ae";
$sc    = new ShopifyClient("mine-329.myshopify.com/", $t, API_KEY, SECRET);
$order = array();
if (!isset($t)) {
    if (!isset($_GET['signature'])) {
        $url = $sc->getAuthorizeUrl("read_orders");
        header('Location: ' . $url);
    }
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $accTok = $sc->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
        echo "token = " . $accTok;
        exit;
        $orders = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array(
            'published_status' => 'published'
        ));
        foreach ($orders as $order) {
            echo $order['id'];
            echo $order['email'];
        }
    }
}
if (isset($t)) {
    $orders               = $sc->call('GET', 'admin/orders.json', array(
        'published_status' => 'published'
    ));
    $myarray              = array();
    $list[]               = array(
        'Name',
        'Email',
        'Financial Status',
        'Paid at',
        'Fulfillment Status',
        'Fulfilled at',
        'Accepts Marketing',
        'Currency',
        'Subtotal',
        'Shipping',
        'Taxes',
        'Total',
        'Discount code',
        'Discount Amount',
        'Shipping Method',
        'Created at',
        'Lineitem quantity',
        'Lineitem name',
        'Lineitem price',
        'Lineitem compare at price',
        'Lineitem sku',
        'Lineitem requires shipping',
        'Lineitem taxable',
        'Lineitem fulfillment status',
        'Billing Name',
        'Billing Street',
        'Billing Address1',
        'Billing Address2',
        'Billing Company',
        'Billing City',
        'Billing Zip',
        'Billing Province',
        'Billing Country',
        'Billing Phone',
        'Shipping Name',
        'Shipping Street',
        'Shipping Address1',
        'Shipping Address2',
        'Shipping Company',
        'Shipping City',
        'Shipping Zip',
        'Shipping Province',
        'Shipping Country',
        'Shipping Phone',
        'Notes',
        'Note Attributes',
        'VAT',
        'Cancelled at',
        'Payment Method',
        'Payment Reference',
        'Refunded Amount',
        'Vendor',
        'Id',
        'Tags'
    );
    $list                 = array_filter($list);
    $empty_note_attribute = "";
    if (empty($order['note_attributes'])) {
        $empty_note_attribute = "";
    } else {
        $empty_note_attribute = $order['note_attributes'];
    }
    $empty_discount_codes = "";
    if (empty($order['discount_codes'])) {
        $empty_discount_codes = "";
    } else {
        $empty_discount_codes = $order['discount_codes'];
    }

    foreach ($orders as $order) {

        $str          = file_get_contents('slim-2.json'); //give the address of json file  
        $str          = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');
        $json_country = json_decode($str, true);
        //Here is the problem you are passing `$str` but you should pass `$json_country`
        if (is_array($json_country)) {
            foreach ($json_country as $key => $value) {
                if (array_search(trim($order['billing_address']['country']), $value)) // Added trim 
                    {
                    $order['billing_address']['country'] = $value['alpha-2'];
                }
                if (isset($order['shipping_address']['country'])) {
                    if (array_search(trim($order['shipping_address']['country']), $value)) // Added trim         
                        {
                        $order['shipping_address']['country'] = $value['alpha-2'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $csv        = file_get_contents('states.csv');
      $csv        = mb_convert_encoding($csv, 'UTF-8');
        $json       = csvToJson($csv);
        $json_state = json_decode($json, true);
        $bilProvin  = trim($order['billing_address']['province']);
        $shpProvin  = '';
        if (isset($order['shipping_address'])) {
            $shpProvin = $order['shipping_address']['province'];

        }
        foreach ($json_state as $keys) { 
            if (array_search($bilProvin, $keys)) // Added trim 
                {
                $order['billing_address']['province'] = substr($keys['var1'], 3);
            }
            if (isset($order['shipping_address'])) {

                if (array_search($shpProvin, $keys)) {

                    $order['shipping_address']['province'] = substr($keys['var1'], 3);
                }
            }
        }




        $orders_lineitem = $order['line_items'];
        $lineitemcount   = 0;
        foreach ($orders_lineitem as $lineitem) {
            /*
            Fulfillment Status
            */
            $fulfill_status = "";
            if (empty($order['fulfillment_status'])) {
                $fulfill_status = "pending";
            } else {
                $fulfill_status = $order['fulfillment_status'];
            }
            /*
            Lineitem Fulfillment Status
            */
            $fulfillment_status = '';
            if (empty($order['fulfillments'][0]['created_at'])) {
                $fulfillment_status = "pending";
            } else {
                $fulfillment_status = $order['line_items'][0]['fulfillment_status'];
            }
            $variants          = "";
            $variants          = $sc->call('GET', "admin/variants/" . $lineitem['variant_id'] . ".json", array(
                'published_status' => 'published'
            ));
            $requires_shipping = "false";
            if ($lineitem['requires_shipping']) {
                $requires_shipping = "true";
            }
            $lineitem_taxable = "false";
            if ($lineitem['taxable']) {
                $lineitem_taxable = "true";
            }
            //** Accepts Marketting **

            $accepts_marketting = "no";
            if ($order['buyer_accepts_marketing']) {
                $accepts_marketting = "yes";
            }
            $shipping = '';
            if (count($order['shipping_lines']) > 0) {
                $shipping = $order['shipping_lines'][0]['price'];
            }
            /* 
            Fulfilled at
            */
            $created_at = '';
            if (count($order['fulfillments']) > 0) {
                $created_at = $order['fulfillments'][0]['created_at'];
            }

            /*
            total tax
            */
            $total_tax = '';
            if (count($order['line_items'][0]['tax_lines']) > 0) {
                $total_tax = $order['line_items'][0]['tax_lines'][0]['price'];
            }

            /*
            Payment reference
            */

            $payment = '';
            if ($order['checkout_id']) {
                $payment = sprintf('c%s.1', $order['checkout_id']);
            }

            /*  
            Refunded Amount 
            */
            $refund_price = '';
            if (count($order['refunds']) > 0) {
                foreach ($order['refunds'] as $refund) {
                    if (count($refund['transactions']) > 0) {
                        $refund_price += $refund['transactions'][0]['receipt']['paid_amount'];
                    }
                }
            }
            if ('pending' == $fulfill_status || 'partial' == $fulfill_status) {
                $created_at = '';
            }

            if ($lineitemcount == 0) {
                array_push($list, array(
                    $order['name'],
                    $order['email'],
                    $order['financial_status'],
                    (($order['financial_status'] != 'partially_refunded') && ($order['financial_status'] != 'refunded') && ($order['financial_status'] != 'authorized') ? $order['created_at'] : null),
                    $fulfill_status,
                    $created_at,
                    $accepts_marketting,
                    $order['currency'],
                    $order['subtotal_price'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $shipping : 0),
                    $order['total_tax'],
                    $order['total_price'],
                    $empty_discount_codes,
                    $order['total_discounts'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_lines'][0]['code'] : null),
                    $order['created_at'],
                    $lineitem['quantity'],
                    $lineitem['name'],
                    $lineitem['price'],
                    $variants['compare_at_price'],
                    $lineitem['sku'],
                    $requires_shipping,
                    $lineitem_taxable,
                    $fulfillment_status,
                    $order['billing_address']['name'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address1'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address1'],
                    $order['billing_address']['address2'],
                    $order['billing_address']['company'],
                    $order['billing_address']['city'],
                    $order['billing_address']['zip'],
                    $order['billing_address']['province'],
                    $order['billing_address']['country'],
                    $order['billing_address']['phone'],
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['name'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address1'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address1'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['address2'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['company'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['city'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['zip'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['province'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['country'] : null),
                    (($shipping > 0) ? $order['shipping_address']['phone'] : null),
                    $order['note'],
                    $empty_note_attribute,
                    $total_tax,
                    $order['cancelled_at'],
                    $order['payment_details']['credit_card_company'],
                    $payment,
                    (($refund_price > 0) ? $refund_price : 0),
                    $lineitem['vendor'],
                    $order['id'],
                    $order['tags']
                ));
            } else {
                array_push($list, array(
                    $order['name'],
                    $order['email'],
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    $empty_discount_codes,
                    '',
                    '',
                    $order['created_at'],
                    $lineitem['quantity'],
                    $lineitem['name'],
                    $lineitem['price'],
                    $variants['compare_at_price'],
                    $lineitem['sku'],
                    $requires_shipping,
                    $lineitem_taxable,
                    $fulfillment_status,
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    '',
                    $lineitem['vendor'],
                    '',
                    $order['tags']
                ));
            }
            $lineitemcount++;
        }
    }
    $order  = $_GET;
    $list[] = array_to_csv_download($myarray, // this array is going to be the second row
        "numbers.csv");
    $list   = array_filter($list);
    array_to_csv_download($list);
    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
}
function array_to_csv_download($list)
{
    $output = fopen("php://output", "w");
    foreach ($list as $row) {
        fputcsv($output, $row);
        //print_r($row); die;
    }
    fclose($output);
}
?>
```

I created one app using above code which is used for download details as csv file fron online store.

Now all the details got it. what my problem is, in the above code, where is `$order['billing_address']['province']`'s value is not shows correctly.

The reason is, I want to add some condition to my above code. If `$order['billing_address']['province']`'s value 'KY', it shows empty field.But i checked

```
$province = '';
if($order['billing_address']['province']! = 'KY') {
$province = $order['billing_address']['province'];
}
```

on above the code `foreach ($json_state as $keys)`, it will display parse error.
I dont know how to add code in my above code. I m new to php.Can any one help me?

Thanks!!!

Comment: `$list[] = array(` is creating a 2D array, calling `array_filter` on that isn't going to get you very far. I think you meant `$list = array()`, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrong:

```
if($order['billing_address']['province']! = 'KY') {
```

correct:

```
if($order['billing_address']['province'] != 'KY') {
```